# How to add multiple chars between string?

Tags: c, split, arduino, insert, addition

I want to add char in my string like '.', '"', '°'... to make it valid for google map location

The code is:

```
void loop() {
    // print the string when a newline arrives:
    if (stringComplete) {
        String BB = inputString.substring(0, 6);
        //String degree = "°";
        //String comma = ;
        //String dot = ".";


        if (BB == signal) {
            String LAT = inputString.substring(7, 17);
            int LATperiod = LAT.indexOf('.');
            int LATzero = LAT.indexOf('0');


            if (LATzero == 0) {
                LAT = LAT.substring(1);
            }


            LAT.setCharAt(2, '°');
            LAT.setCharAt(5, '\'');
            LAT.remove(5,1);
            LAT.setCharAt(8, '.');
            LAT.setCharAt(12, 'N');



            String LON = inputString.substring(20, 31);
            int LONperiod = LON.indexOf('.');
            int LONTzero = LON.indexOf('0');
            if (LONTzero == 0) {
                LON = LON.substring(1);
            }
            LON.setCharAt(2, '°');
            LON.setCharAt(5, '\'');
            LON.remove(5,1);
            LON.setCharAt(8, '.');
            LON.setCharAt(12, 'E');




            Serial.println("==LATITUDE==");
            Serial.println(LAT);
            Serial.println("==LONGITUDE==");
            Serial.println(LON);
            Serial.println("=========================");

        }
```

**Output:**
==LATITUDE==
2432.06746
==LONGITUDE==
6713.13658

And I want to add chars in this string like it like:
**24°32'06.746N 67°13'13.658E**

Comment: Are you aware of https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat and https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr ? Please read that and then explain in more detail what got you stuck. It should enable you to find the first blank or "." in input and then copy parts of it to destination intertwined with the desired new characters.

Comment: what is default format of inputString?

Answer (score 0):

**`sscanf` + `sprintf` is your solution here.**

First let's get needed parts of inputString:

```
String LAT = inputString.substring(7, 17);

char deg[3], min[3], sec_main[3], sec_frac[4];
sscanf(LAT.c_str(), "%2s%2s.%2s%s", deg, min, sec_main, sec_frac);
```

Then, collect all these parsed parts into one string:

```
char latitude[15];
sprintf(latitude, "%s°%s'%s.%s", deg, min, sec_main, sec_frac);
```